# How to replace non-alphabetic AND numeric characters in a string in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I understand that to replace non-alphanumeric characters in a string a code would be as follows:

```
words = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  str).split()
```

However, `^\w` replaces non-alphanumeric characters. I want to replace both non-alphabetic and numeric chars in a string like:

```
"baa!!!!! baa sheep23? baa baa"
```

and I want it to have an outcome like this:

```
 "baa baa sheep baa baa"
```

If I do `words = re.sub("[^\w\d]", " ",  str).split()`, I get an outcome with numeric characters, like `'sheep23'`. I guess that it could be because `"^"` affects  `\d` as well and it counts as if I want the non-numeric characters removed. How do I do this right?

Comment: While all answers correct, none explain why OP's code doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this regex?

```
[^\w]|\d
```

EDIT:

As @Avinash said this not removes `_`. If you want to remove also `_` use:

```
[^\w]|[\d_]
```

and if you also want to replace multiple spaces with a single one use:

```
([^\w]|[\d_])+
```

Here's your example with an addition of underscores:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s = "baa!!!!! baa sheep23? baa baa___"

In [3]: re.sub("([^\w]|[\d_])+", " ",  s)
Out[3]: 'baa baa sheep baa baa '

In [4]: re.sub("([^\w]|[\d_])+", " ",  s).split()
Out[4]: ['baa', 'baa', 'sheep', 'baa', 'baa']
```

Comment: thank you, I was not sure how to do this in regex and that's what I was looking for

Comment: it won't remove `_` and it removes spaces also.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
>>> from string import punctuation, digits
>>> s = "baa!!!!! baa sheep23? baa baa"
>>> s.translate(None, punctuation+digits)
'baa baa sheep baa baa'
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to do regex here, just a simple comprehension will work:

```
>>> import string
>>> word = "baa!!!!! baa sheep23? baa baa"
>>> "".join([l for l in word if l in string.ascii_letters+string.whitespace])
'baa baa sheep baa baa'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
[^a-zA-Z]
```

This matches anything that is not a letter.

Or this if you want to keep spaces:

[^a-zA-Z\s]

Answer (score 0):

Through `re.sub` function,

```
>>> s = "baa!!!!! baa sheep23? baa baa"
>>> m = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z ]', "", s)
>>> m
'baa baa sheep baa baa'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing every non-letter with a space *then* split you can do it all in one go:

```
>>> re.split("[^a-zA-Z]+", "baa!!!!! baa sheep23? baa baa")
['baa', 'baa', 'sheep', 'baa', 'baa']
```

`[^\w]` is equivalent to `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` (modulo language settings), you need to keep in your character class only what you want - and `[^a-zA-Z]` obviously includes spaces.